# Install Piranha on Centos 7

Tags: centos, load-balance, piranha

I have tried install Piranha on Centos 7, but

```
 yum install piranha ipvsadm -y
```

Not found the package. Is necessary modify repos or other command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RHEL 7, on which CentOS is based, piranha was replaced with [keepalived and haproxy](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Load_Balancer_Administration/index.html).